# Tengo una pregunta sobre mi programa de python

Tags: python, lista

Tengo que hacer un programa que consiste en un menú para incluir datos sobre estudiantes, y luego consultarlos y agregar más datos. Tnego que incluir el número de carné estudiantil y luego con ese número consultar por lo datos de esa persona y agregar sus notas en varias asignaturas. Pero no logro hacer que me imprima unicamente los datos de la persona que consulté, me tira todos los datos de las otras personas que están en la lista(porque está hecho con listas). A pesar que de he consultado varios libros y he pedido ayuda a compañeros lo logro llegar a lo que necesito. Les agradecería si me indican cual es mi error y como debo corregirlo.

**Mi código**

```
def inte(EsInteger):
    try:
         val=eval(EsInteger)
         if type(val) == int:
            return True
         else:
            return False
    except:
        return False

def estudiantes():
    estudiante=[]
    while input("Desea registrar un estudiante: ").lower()== 'y':
        cantidad= input("Ingrese el número de estudiantes que desea matricular: ")
        if inte(cantidad):
            cantidad= eval(cantidad)
            while cantidad >0:
                estudiante.append([])
                cantidad -=1
            for est in estudiante:
                carne= est.append (input("Ingrese el carne del estudiante a matricular: "))
                nombre= est.append (input("Ingrese el nombre del estudiante: " ))
                fecha=est.append (input("Ingrese la fecha de nacimiento del estudiante: "))
            if input("Ingrese el número de carné que desea consultar: ")== carne:
                print (estudiante)
            return estudiante
```

Comment: Hola, Priscila, ¿no crees que seria mejor consultar el carne de un estudiantes después de haber añadido los estudiantes que deseas? sino, te estaría solicitando consultar el carne de a un estudiante cuando lo unico que deseas es añadir estudiantes a la lista.

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer mas facil y sencillo la funcionalidad de tu programa decidi separar el codigo. Agrege una función que se encargue de buscar al estudiante, en caso el usuario quiera hacerlo. Ademas cambie las listas por diccionarios el beneficio de esto es que facilita la busquedad y se tiene un registro mas ordenado de los estudiantes.

**Funcion Buscar estudiante**

```py
def buscar(carne,estudiante):
     consulta = input("Ingrese el número de carné que desea consultar: ")
     #verificamos si el estudiante se encuentra en el diccionario
     if  consulta in estudiante:
         #obtenemos su nombre y fecha de nacimiento
         nombre = estudiante[consulta]['nombre']
         nacimiento = estudiante[consulta]['fecha_nacimiento']
         #retornamos un bonito mensaje
         return f'el estudiante con carne {consulta} es {nombre}, con fecha de nacimiento {nacimiento}'
     else:
         return f"No esxiste el estudiante con el carne {consulta}"
```

**Informacion**
Como dije,  se cambio el tipo de dato de la variable `estudiantes` a un diccionario, si no estas familiarizado te resultara algo confuso (o no) pero te explico, puedes pensar en un diccionario como un **JSON**, solo que aqui todo gira entorno a la `clave/valor`, pues un diccionario esta compuesto por una clave **Única** y un valor, de esta forma

```py
diccionario = {
     "Antonio": "Se fue de viaje",
     "Maria": "Cuida a su perro"
}
```

donde `Antonio` y `Maria` son las claves y el valor es `Se fue de viaje` y `Cuida a su perro`, las claves deben ser unicas y son inmutables, es ecir no puedes cambiar su valor, pero si puedes cambiar el valor asignado a la clave.

En python crear un diccionario y acceder a sus valores es muy parecido a como lo harias con una lista

```py
diccionario = {}

#añadiendo valores
diccionario["Jose"] = "es alto"
#añade el valor de "Jose" con su respectivo valor

print(diccionario)
#{"Jose": "es alto"}

#para obtener un valor solo accedemos a la clave

#obteniendo valores
print(diccionario["Jose"])
```

**funcion estudiantes**

```py
def estudiantes():
    estudiante={} #se cambio a diccionario
    while input("Desea registrar un estudiante? ").lower()== 'y':
        cantidad= input("Ingrese el número de estudiantes que desea matricular: ")
        if inte(cantidad):
            #iteramos en el rango del numero de estudiantes a ingresar
            for est in range(int(cantidad)):
              carne = input("Ingrese el carne del estudiante a matricular: ")
              nombre = input("Ingrese el nombre del estudiante: " )
              fecha = input("Ingrese la fecha de nacimiento del estudiante: ")
              #verificamos que no exista el estudiante
              if carne not in estudiantes: 
                #agregamos al estudiante
                estudiante[carne] = {"nombre":nombre,"fecha_nacimiento":fecha}
              else:
                print(f"el estudiannte con el carne {carne} ya existe")

            #preguntamos si quiere buscar  
            c = input("desea buscar algun estudiante? ").lower()
            if c == 'y':
              #hacemos la busquedad
              return buscar(c,estudiante)
            else:
                #terminamos el programa
                return "Estudiantes agregados"
        else:
          #le pedimos que ingrese un numero
          print("Introduzca un numero")
    #en caso no quiera registrar un estudiante, salimos
    else:
        return "Saliendo.."
```

**Probamos**

```py
estudiante = estudiantes()
print(estudiante)
```